# How to yield nothing if condition is not fulfilled instead of an alternative using np.where?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question concerning `numpy.where`. Beside a condition, the parameters of `np.where` require both x and y.

- x: x is yielded where the condition is true.
- y: y is yielded/used where the condition is not fulfilled.

The part of the related code could look like the following:

```
BypassZero = np.where(f > 0.00000000000001, f, -8.5)
```

My question is: is it possible to tell `np.where` that "nothing" for y instead of -8.5 should be used? An example: if the condition is to use values only higher than 0.00000000000001, as shown above in the code, and this condition is not fulfilled in one numeric value out of a row (of many values), np.where should ignore this step and directly jump to the next numeric value in the row, instead of using -8.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: After some suggestions from the comments on my original answer and clarification from the OP, the task is to select those values which satisfy a condition and not include other values.

e.g. If I wanted to select all even numbers and exclude all odd numbers, I'd do it this way:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
evens = x[x % 2 == 0]  # select even numbers only
print(evens)
```

The output:

```
[ 2  4  6  8 10]
```

In your case:

```
result = f[f > 0.00000000000001]
```

As Timus pointed out, **np.where** is not necessary at all.

Comment: Do you really need the `where`?

Comment: After answering the question I've been thinking about it as well... You are right, it is not necessary at all. For my example: x[x % 2 == 0] = -1 will work perfectly fine.

Comment: `x[np.where(x % 2 == 0)] = -1` is quivalent to `np.where(x % 2 != 0, x, -1)`  which is equivalent to `x[x % 2 == 0] = -1`.

Comment: Oooh, okay, I think I got it now. I'll edit my answer. Regarding the example, this is a quick fix for the odd-even numbers problem: "evens = x[x % 2 == 0]". This will select only the even numbers.

Comment: @waykiki, your answer can be close to the solution. The only difference is that I don't want to keep values that do not fulfil the condition. Instead, values that do not fulfil the condition should no longer be part of the result/output. These values should be treated like they are non-existent, i.e., no longer be part of the output. At the same time, no values need to be changed or replaced by another value.

Comment: @waykiki, you solved the problem, thank you a lot. After implementing your code into my code, I realised that my code as a whole including your code leads to another problem. This is not due to your code, but related to the general combination of codes. I should probably create a new question instead of completly changing this one. I accept your answer as the one solving the problem. Thanks!